# How can I port msvc++ code with non-dependent names in templates to Linux?

Tags: c++, templates

I can deal with porting platform dependent functions. I have a problem that the compilers I tried on Linux (clang and g++) do not accept the following code, while the msvc++ compiler does:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
protected:
    T Value;
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    void setValue(const T& inValue){
        Value = inValue;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Derived<int> tmp;
    tmp.setValue(0);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Derived<T>::setValue(const T&)’:
main.cpp:11:3: error: ‘Value’ was not declared in this scope
```

I believe this due to the use of a non-dependent name (`Value`) in the second class. [More information](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/).

The problem is that I have a very large code base, in which this type of code is used very often. I understand that it is wrong when looking at the standard. However it is very convenient not having to write `this->` or `Base<T>::` in front of every use of `Value`. Even writing `using Base<T>::Value;` at the start of the derived class is problematic when you use ~20 members of the base class.

So my question is: are there compilers for Linux that allow this kind of code (with or without extra compiler switches)? Or are there **small** modifications that will allow this code to compile on Linux?

Comment: The only sensible modification is to fix the broken code; even if some compiler _does_ support this, it's a bug and could be fixed at any time.

Comment: Actually, even if you have such a construct several hundred times in your code, fixing it should not take you more than a few hours using a decent text editor, since the compiler tells you exactly where you have to change your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140632/how-can-i-port-msvc-code-with-non-dependent-names-in-templates-to-linux). From the few comments here and the answers there I reach the same conclusion: I have to fix my code. Adding my own answer so I can mark this question as accepted/resolved.